# How can i add same multiple html element with js?

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

I want to build a note taker app with html css and js but when i want add second note there is a problem.

```js
let myNote = "";
let myTitle = "";
let noteInput = document.getElementById("note-input");
let titleInput = document.getElementById("title-input");
let title = document.getElementById("title");
let note = document.getElementById("first-note-p");
let addButton = document.getElementById("addButton");
let removeButton = document.getElementById("remove-button");
let newDiv = document.createElement("div");
let newP = document.createElement("p");
let newH3 = document.createElement("h3");
let newButton = document.createElement("button");
let notePlace = document.getElementById("note-place");
let button = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
let div = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
let paragrapgh = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
let head3 = document.getElementsByTagName("h3");
let tally = 0;

const addNote = () => {
  myNote = noteInput.value;
  myTitle = titleInput.value;
  notePlace.appendChild(newDiv);
  div[tally].appendChild(newH3);
  div[tally].appendChild(newP);
  div[tally].appendChild(newButton);
  notePlace = document.getElementById("note-place");
  head3[tally].innerText = myTitle;
  paragrapgh[tally].innerText = myNote;
  button[tally + 1].innerText = "remove";
  tally += 1;
};

const removeNote = () => {
  title.innerHTML = "";
  note.innerHTML = "";
};

addButton.onclick = addNote;
```

```html
<h1>Take your notes</h1>
<input id="title-input" onfocus="this.value=''" type="text" value="title" />
<input id="note-input" onfocus="this.value=''" type="text" value="note" />
<button id="addButton">add</button>
<div id="note-place"></div>
```

I use addNote function to add a new note but for second note I encounter to the following error.

```
Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'innerText')
    at HTMLButtonElement.addNote (notetaker.js:37:26)
```

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Please include all relevant code, including html, to form a minimal reproducible example. You seem to append to `notePlace` before you initialize it. Which `innerText` is erroring? Have you logged the element you are attempting to set the innerText of?

Comment: It's not clear what `div`, `head3`, `button` and `paragrapgh` (sic) are.  If paragrapgh is just a typo, it could easily cause that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem with your attempt is that you're selecting the elements before actually creating and appending them to the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) and that will lead to problems because those elements that were initially selected are no longer there when a new note is added.

The fix is fairly easy, select the elements at the time you create a new note. Actually, I won't just stop here and I will happily invite you to follow along with my answer as we approach your task (of making notes and showing them in the screen) in a better approach that, i think, will be more helpful than just giving a fix.

So, here's what we're going to do, we're firstly go by tackling the task and see what are the main sub-tasks to do in order to have a working demo (with add and remove notes features):

- To have a better performance, we'll select and cache the elements that we will use `extensively` in our task. Mainly, the element `div#note-place` should be cached because we're going to use many times when we add and remove notes.
- The `input`s, for the note `title` and `text`, the `button` that adds a note, those elements should be cached as well.
- The main thing we will be doing is creating some elements and appending them to `div#note-place` so we can assign that sub-task to a separate function (that we will create). This function will create an element, add the wanted attributes (text, `class` etc...) then it returns that created element.
- At this stage, our solution has started to take shape. Now, to create a note we will listen for the `click` event on the add note `button` and then we will have a listener that will handle the creation of the new note based on the values found on the `input`s and then append that to the `DOM`. We will use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to attach a `click` event listener on the add note `button` (modern `JS`, no more `onclick`s!).
- Now, for the remove note feature. The initial thinking that comes to mind is that we will listen for `click` events on the remover buttons and then do the work. This can work, but here's a better solution, [`Event Delegation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation), which basically allow us to have **1** listener set on `div#note-place` element that will call the remove note logic only when a remove button was clicked (see the code below for more info).

So, let's not take more time, the live demo below should allow you to easily understand what's being said:

```js
/** cache the elemnts that we know we will use later on */
const notesContainer = document.getElementById('note-place'),
  titleInp = document.getElementById('title-input'),
  noteInp = document.getElementById('note-input'),
  addNoteBtn = document.getElementById('add-note-btn'),
  /** this class will be added to all remove note buttons This will allow us to catch clicks on those buttons using event delegation */
  noteRemoverBtnClass = 'note-remover-btn',
  /**
   * a simple function that create an element, add the requested attribute and return the newly created element.
   * tag: the tag name of the element to create (like div, h3 etc...).
   * text: the text to show on the element (using textContent attribute).
   * attributes: an object that holds "key: value" pairs where the keys are the attributes (like id, type etc...) and the values are the values for each attribute set on that parameter (see usage below).
   */
  createElement = (tag, text, attributes) => {
    const el = document.createElement(tag);
    attributes = attributes || {};
    !!text && (el.textContent = text);
    for (let attr in attributes)
      attributes.hasOwnProperty(attr) && el.setAttribute(attr, attributes[attr]);
    return el;
  };

/** listen for click events on the add note button */
addNoteBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  /** create a div that will wrap the new note */
  const noteEl = createElement('div');
  /** 
   * create an "h3" for the note title, a "p" for the note text and a "button" that acts as the remove note button
   * then loop through them and add them to the note wrapper that we just created
   */
  [
    createElement('h3', titleInp.value),
    createElement('p', noteInp.value),
    createElement('button', 'Remove', {
      type: 'button',
      class: noteRemoverBtnClass
    })
  ].forEach(el => noteEl.appendChild(el));
  /** append the entire note element (including the "h3", "p"p and "button" to "div#note-place" */
  notesContainer.appendChild(noteEl);
});

/** implement event delegation by listening to click events on "div#note-place" and execute a set of logic (to remove a note) only when the clicked element is actually a remove button (thanks to "noteRemoverBtnClass" that we add to each created remove button)  */
notesContainer.addEventListener('click', e => e.target.classList.contains(noteRemoverBtnClass) && e.target.parentNode.remove());
```

```html
<h1>Take your notes</h1>
<input id="title-input" onfocus="this.value=''" type="text" value="title" />
<input id="note-input" onfocus="this.value=''" type="text" value="note" />
<button id="add-note-btn">add</button>
<div id="note-place"></div>
```

> The above code sample is definitely **NOT** the only way to get things done, it only aims to be simple while recommending the use of some modern `JS` technics and logics. There always be more ways to do the task and even some better ways to do it.